# Как реализовать такой квадратный селектор на Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть задача, реализовать такой селектор:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Схема работы:

- Зажимаем мышку на жёлтом кругу
- Тянем в нужную сторону
- Получаем данные в зависимости от положения жёлтого круга

Подскажите, пожалуйста, подход к реализации этого селектора или ваши идеи, или даже пример.

Буду рад любой помощи, спасибо!

Comment: А что пробовали, что не получается?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko не пробовал пока делать, потому что попросту не понимаю с чего начать (

Comment: Начните с простого, потом усложняйте. Появятся вопросы - задавайте конкретные вопросы. Начните с верстки, потом добавляйте события, потом пишите логику определения положения(ну или основывайтесь на событиях). Здесь вам помогут с конкретным вопросом, а не таким ТЗ.

Comment: тут я думаю обычной вёрсткой не обойтись, думаю канвах, хотя могу и ошибаться

Comment: Можно канвас, можно свг, а можно и обычными дивами. Глаза бояться - а руки делают.

Comment: @ryzen, можно напишу это на `jQuery` как ответ сюда, просто так, ради собственного интереса?))

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 конечно, мне бы очень было интересно посмотреть на такую реализацию

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В общем-то всё это тяжело объяснить, но лучше готовый пример, чем отсутствие примера.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
const curve = {}, control = {}, knob = {}
let frame_id = null, width = 0, height = 0
resize(); drawAll()

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  resize()
  drawAll()
})

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', startDragging)
canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', startDragging)

function startDragging(e) {
  const { pageX, pageY } = e.type === 'mousedown' ? e : e.changedTouches[0]

  const mouse = { x: pageX, y: pageY }
  const _knob = { x: knob.x[0], y: knob.y[0],r: knob.r }

  if (!pointCircleCollision(mouse, _knob)) return

  update()

  const x_start = pageX - knob.x[0]
  const y_start = pageY - knob.y[0]

  if (e.type === 'mousedown') {
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', continueDragging)
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDragging)
  }

  if (e.type === 'touchstart') {
    canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', continueDragging)
    canvas.addEventListener('touchend', stopDragging)
  }

  function continueDragging(e) {
    let { pageX, pageY } = e.type === 'mousemove' ? e : e.changedTouches[0]

    const x = pageX - x_start
    const y = pageY - y_start

    knob.x[1] = minmax(x, knob.x_edges[0], knob.x_edges[1])
    knob.y[1] = minmax(y, knob.y_edges[0], knob.y_edges[1])
  }

  function stopDragging(e) {
    knob.x[1] = control.x + control.w / 2
    knob.y[1] = control.y + control.h / 2

    setTimeout(() => cancelAnimationFrame(frame_id), 500)

    if (e.type === 'mouseup') {
      canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', continueDragging)
      canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopDragging)
    }

    if (e.type === 'touchend') {
      canvas.removeEventListener('touchmove', continueDragging)
      canvas.removeEventListener('touchend', stopDragging)
    }
  }
}

function pointCircleCollision(point, circle) {
  const dx = point.x - circle.x
  const dy = point.y - circle.y
  const distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)

  return distance < circle.r
}

function minmax(v, min, max) {
  return Math.max(min, Math.min(v, max))
}

function drawControl() {
  context.fillStyle = 'lightgreen'
  context.fillRect(control.x, control.y, control.w, control.h)
}

function drawKnob() {
  knob.x[0] += (knob.x[1] - knob.x[0]) * 0.23
  knob.y[0] += (knob.y[1] - knob.y[0]) * 0.23

  context.fillStyle = knob.c
  context.beginPath()
  context.arc(knob.x[0], knob.y[0], knob.r, 0, Math.PI * 2)
  context.fill()
}

function drawCurve() {
  const x_step = 1 / (control.w - knob.r * 2)
  const y_step = 1 / (control.h - knob.r * 2)

  const dx = knob.x[0] - (control.x + control.w / 2)
  const dy = knob.y[0] - (control.y + control.h / 2)

  const x_percentage = +(x_step * 2 * dx).toFixed(5)
  const y_percentage = +(y_step * 2 * dy).toFixed(5)

  const curve_point_x = ((curve.x + curve.w) / 2) + curve.w * x_percentage
  const curve_point_y = curve.y + innerHeight * 0.3 * y_percentage

  context.strokeStyle = 'brown'
  context.lineWidth = (width + height) * 0.004
  context.lineCap = 'round'
  context.beginPath()
  context.moveTo(curve.x, curve.y)
  context.quadraticCurveTo(curve_point_x, curve_point_y, curve.w, curve.y)
  context.stroke()
}

function drawAll() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)
  drawCurve()
  drawControl()
  drawKnob()
}

function update() {
  drawAll()
  frame_id = requestAnimationFrame(update)
}

function resize() {
  width = canvas.width = innerWidth
  height = canvas.height = innerHeight

  curve.x = width * 0.3
  curve.y = height * 0.3
  curve.w = width * 0.7

  control.x = width * 0.3
  control.y = height * 0.6
  control.w = width * 0.4
  control.h = height * 0.3

  const knob_x = control.x + control.w / 2
  const knob_y = control.y + control.h / 2
  knob.x = [knob_x, knob_x]
  knob.y = [knob_y, knob_y]
  knob.r = (width + height) * 0.02
  knob.c = 'tomato'

  knob.x_edges = [control.x + knob.r, control.x + control.w - knob.r]
  knob.y_edges = [control.y + knob.r, control.y + control.h - knob.r]
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

---

`knob.x[0]` и `knob.y[0]` - плавно меняющиеся значения

`knob.x[1]` и `knob.y[1]` - финальные позиции ручки

---

Главный механизм тут, естественно `drag'n'drop`. Вот типичный пример, как это сделать для `canvas элемента`:

```js
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', startDragging)
canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', startDragging)

function startDragging(e) {
  // координаты нажатия мыши или пальца
  const { pageX, pageY } = e.type === 'mousedown' ? e : e.changedTouches[0]

  // проверка на то, произошло ли нажатие внутри объекта
  if (!collision(mouse, object)) return

  // координаты нажатия внутри объекта
  const x_start = pageX - object.x
  const y_start = pageY - object.y

  if (e.type === 'mousedown') {
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', continueDragging)
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDragging)
  }

  if (e.type === 'touchstart') {
    canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', continueDragging)
    canvas.addEventListener('touchend', stopDragging)
  }

  function continueDragging(e) {
    // координаты движения мыши или пальца
    const { pageX, pageY } = e.type === 'mousemove' ? e : e.changedTouches[0]

    // перемещение объекта
    const x = pageX - x_start
    const y = pageY - y_start
    
    object.x = x
    object.y = y
  }

  function stopDragging(e) {
    if (e.type === 'mouseup') {
      canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', continueDragging)
      canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopDragging)
    }

    if (e.type === 'touchend') {
      canvas.removeEventListener('touchmove', continueDragging)
      canvas.removeEventListener('touchend', stopDragging)
    }
  }
}
```

---

Функция для проверки на то, произошло ли нажатие внутри **круглого** объекта:

```js
function pointCircleCollision(point, circle) {
  const dx = point.x - circle.x
  const dy = point.y - circle.y
  const distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)

  return distance < circle.r
}
```

---

Если ручку делать `dom-элементом`, то код будет много отличаться, но разницы, в принципе, никакой нету.

Comment: Поставлю плюс за разъяснение, но думаю многие хотят увидеть готовый вариант)

Comment: что-то я не понял как ответ с вопросом связан

Comment: @Grundy в каком месте он не связан? Я могу полностью на основе этого ответа сделать то, что у него изображено на картинке.

Comment: сделай. Но у него на картинке не показано, что именно должно происходить при перетягивании

Comment: @Grundy "Получаем данные в зависимости от положения жёлтого круга". Я эти данные выразил в виде изгиба линии.

Comment: Вот я и говорю, что из-за этого не понятна связь с вопросом.

Comment: спасибо! Возьму код для точки входа)

Answer (score 2):

Впервые написал "Drag'n'Drop", думаю что криво, буду рад если укажут на ошибку по нему..

По поводу механики.. Я решил выводить значения следующим образом:
У нас есть "коорданатная плоскость", думаю как она работает объяснять не надо.. Думаю визуально понятно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получить их можно как при едином нажатии, так и при движение, при помощи переменной `moveParam.move.value`.

```js
let moveParam = {
  isMove: false,
  areaEl: $('.-area'), moveEl: $('.-move'),
  //
  pointerInherit: $('.-move').css('pointer-events')
};

moveParam.areaEl.on({
  'mousedown': function(e) {
    if(moveParam.isMove === false) {
      moveParam.isMove = true;
      $('body').addClass('--no-select');
      //
      moveParam.move = {
        x: e.pageX - moveParam.areaEl.offset().left,
        y: e.pageY - moveParam.areaEl.offset().top,
        w: moveParam.moveEl.width(),
        h: moveParam.moveEl.height()
      };
      moveParam.area = {
        w: moveParam.areaEl.width(),
        h: moveParam.areaEl.height(),
        size: {
          w: moveParam.areaEl.width() - (moveParam.move.w / 2),
          h: moveParam.areaEl.height() - (moveParam.move.h / 2)
        },
        start: {
          x: moveParam.move.w / 2,
          y: moveParam.move.h / 2
        },
        end: {
          x: moveParam.areaEl.width() - (moveParam.move.w / 2),
          y: moveParam.areaEl.height() - (moveParam.move.h / 2)
        }
      };
      //
      moveParam.move.value = {
        x: ((moveParam.area.w/2) - (moveParam.area.w - moveParam.move.x)) / ((moveParam.area.w - moveParam.move.w)/2),
        y: ((moveParam.area.h - moveParam.move.y) - (moveParam.area.h/2)) / ((moveParam.area.h - moveParam.move.h)/2),
      };
      //
      moveParam.moveEl.css({'left': moveParam.move.x, 'top': moveParam.move.y});
    }
  }
});

$(document).on({
  'mousemove': function(e) {
    if(moveParam.isMove === true) {
      moveParam.move.x = e.pageX - moveParam.areaEl.offset().left;
      moveParam.move.y = e.pageY - moveParam.areaEl.offset().top;
      //
      if(moveParam.move.x >= moveParam.area.end.x)   moveParam.move.x = moveParam.area.end.x;
      if(moveParam.move.y >= moveParam.area.end.y)   moveParam.move.y = moveParam.area.end.y;
      if(moveParam.move.x <= moveParam.area.start.x) moveParam.move.x = moveParam.area.start.x;
      if(moveParam.move.y <= moveParam.area.start.y) moveParam.move.y = moveParam.area.start.y;
      //
      moveParam.move.value = {
        x: ((moveParam.area.w/2) - (moveParam.area.w - moveParam.move.x)) / ((moveParam.area.w - moveParam.move.w)/2),
        y: ((moveParam.area.h - moveParam.move.y) - (moveParam.area.h/2)) / ((moveParam.area.h - moveParam.move.h)/2)
      };
      //
      console.clear();
      console.log(moveParam.move.value);
      //
      moveParam.moveEl.css({'left': moveParam.move.x, 'top': moveParam.move.y});
    }
  },
  'mouseup': function(){
    if(moveParam.isMove === true) {
      moveParam.isMove = false;
      $('body').removeClass('--no-select');
      moveParam.moveEl.css('pointer-events', moveParam.pointerInherit);
    }
  }
});

function MoveInput(x, y) {
  x = Number(x); y = Number(y);
  if((x >= -1 && x <= 1) && (y >= -1 && y <= 1)) {
    x = moveParam.areaEl.width()/2 - (moveParam.areaEl.width()/2 * x) * -1;
    y = moveParam.areaEl.height()/2 - (moveParam.areaEl.height()/2 * y);
    moveParam.moveEl.css({'left': x, 'top': y});
  }
} MoveInput(.5, -.5); // Входные данные
```

```css
body {
  background: #0a0b0b;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,'Roboto','Helvetica Neue',Geneva,"Noto Sans Armenian","Noto Sans Bengali","Noto Sans Cherokee","Noto Sans Devanagari","Noto Sans Ethiopic","Noto Sans Georgian","Noto Sans Hebrew","Noto Sans Kannada","Noto Sans Khmer","Noto Sans Lao","Noto Sans Osmanya","Noto Sans Tamil","Noto Sans Telugu","Noto Sans Thai",sans-serif,arial,Tahoma,verdana;
  /* for snippet */
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.change-area {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 250px;
  color: #8e8e8e;
}

.change-area h1 {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  padding: 0;
  font: inherit;
}

.change-area .select {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.change-area .select .option {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: calc(50% - 4px);
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.05);
  padding: 14px 6px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.change-area .select .option:nth-child(odd) {margin-right: 8px;}
.change-area .select .option:nth-last-child(n+3) {margin-bottom: 8px;}

.change-area .select .option:hover {background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);}
.change-area .select .option.--selected {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  color: #222;
}

.change-area .range {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.05);
  padding: 8px 14px;
  margin: 12px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  --area-col: 6;
  --area-row: 4;
  --area-grid-color: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}

.change-area .range .-area {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to right, var(--area-grid-color), transparent 1.25px) repeat-x left top / calc((100% / var(--area-col)) - (1.25px / var(--area-col))) 100%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--area-grid-color), transparent 1.25px) repeat-y left top / 100% calc((100% / var(--area-row)) - (1.25px / var(--area-row)));
  cursor: move;
}

.change-area .range .-area::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: calc(100% / var(--area-col) * var(--area-row));
  z-index: -1;
}

.change-area .range .label {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: .75;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
}

.change-area .range .label.-up,
.change-area .range .label.-down {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.change-area .range .label.-up {top: 5px;}
.change-area .range .label.-down {bottom: 5px;}

.change-area .range .label.-left,
.change-area .range .label.-right {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.change-area .range .label.-left {left: 5px;}
.change-area .range .label.-right {right: 5px;}

.change-area .range .-move {
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ffbe3f;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
}

.change-area .submit {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.05);
  padding: 14px 8px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.change-area .submit:hover {background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);}


.--no-select {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="change-area">
  <h1>Характеристики</h1>
  <div class="select">
    <div class="option --selected">Нос</div>
    <div class="option">Брови</div>
    <div class="option">Глаза</div>
    <div class="option">Губы</div>
    <div class="option">Лоб</div>
    <div class="option">Скулы</div>
    <div class="option">Челюсть</div>
    <div class="option">Подбородок</div>
  </div>
  <div class="range">
    <div class="-area">
      <div class="label -up">Кверху</div>
      <div class="label -right">Широкий</div>
      <div class="label -down">Низкий</div>
      <div class="label -left">Узкий</div>
      <div class="-move"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="submit">Готово</div>
</div>
```

Вариант написан на jQuery, потому что вот - [коммент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1162266/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0-javascript?noredirect=1#comment2016442_1162266)

---

UPD: Добавил "входные данные".